# Qt: How to display QComboBox inside QTableWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt

I’m trying to display a QComboBox inside a QTableWidgetItem by setting it as its child, using this code:

```
QComboBox* qcb;
int r,c;
//......
qcb->setParent((QWidget*)tableWidget->item(r,c));
```

but that didn’t the job.

so how to fix that? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do this via the `QTableWidget` object itself.

1. Firstly you create your QComboBox
2. then call `void QTableWidget::setCellWidget ( int row, int column, QWidget * widget )`

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget

Comment: That will only work with cells not if you want to set a custom header widget

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to add a widget to a QTableWidget with

```
void QTableWidget::setCellWidget ( int row, int column, QWidget * widget )
```

and accessing it by

```
QWidget * QTableWidget::cellWidget ( int row, int column ) const
```